# Ruby on Rails, image compilation and precompilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just deployed a rails app and I am having an error when I load a page saying:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

In the production.log I see that message:

```
Started GET "/" for 128.179.252.130 at 2014-11-30 08:32:28 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

ActionView::Template::Error (./icons/icon_nameplate.png isn't precompiled):
37:<ul class="dropdown-menu">
38:
39:<li>
40:    <%= menu_dropdown('Profile', "./icons/icon_nameplate.png", "Nameplate Icon", current_user) %>
41:</li>
```

So I believe the error comes from this part of the message:

```
./icons/icon_nameplate.png isn't precompiled
```

I searched the internet, found three possible solution, none of which did work:

```
1. config.assets.compile = true (in production.rb file)
2. config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif] (still in production.rb file)
3. bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

All of this changed absolutely nothing, and the website still shows the same error. So I am turning for you to help.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: are you using something like heroku or a your own vps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally did the trick for me is completely restart the rails app. This is described in the link below.

The recommended version did the trick for me which is:

Create (or update) a file called **restart.txt** in the tmp folder of your Rails application on the server.

After that no problem at all.

Cheers